# the scrollbar is not working in the window of tkinter please suggest me the solution of it

Tags: python, tkinter

i am just trying to set the scrollbar for the canvas window which have many of the elements as checkbuttons of tkinter for the selection of multiple items at a time. i was just created it using canvas method create_window and create new window and put Frame into it. then for every element (for every Checkbutton) I am just creating new frame every time. in the window frame of canvas. and attach the canvas to the scrollbar but it does not work. so if anyone have the solution of it please let me know also.

Note: please do not change the width and the height of any frame and canvas and please do not use pack method of widget where i use place method for widgets. it will change my desired result which i am getting using this method the only problem is that the scrollbar is not working.

```
def Item_List(self):
    list_heading=Label(self.root,text="what would you prefer to eat? ",font=("open sans condensed",13,"bold"),fg="aqua",bg="purple",padx=4)
    list_heading.place(x=350,y=85)
    Main_Frame=Frame(self.root,width=218,height=370)
    canvas=Canvas(Main_Frame,highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.place(x=0,y=0,width=218,height=366)
    Main_Frame.place(x=351,y=115)
    scroll = Scrollbar(self.root, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
    scroll.place(x=552,y=115,height=370,width=15)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set,highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.bind('<Configure>',lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
    Content_Frame=Frame(canvas)
    canvas.create_window((0,0),window=Content_Frame,anchor=NW)
    self.Items=self.Item_Des_Data.keys()
    for item in range(1,101):
        food=Frame(Content_Frame,width=200,height=30,bg="white")
        foodItem = StringVar()
        foodItem.set("0")
        checkbox = Checkbutton(food, text=f"item{item}", variable=foodItem, onvalue=f"item{item}", border=2, bg="white")
        checkbox.place(x=10,y=10)
        food.pack()
```

[image: i was did this and i am getting my desired result except the scrollbar working, it does not work i do not know why if it is working then i have no issue at all in this code.]

Comment: Fix the code block formatting.  It is hard to read.

Comment: You have put the scrollbar at x=552 which is outside the viewable area of `Main_Frame` with width=218.